# why there is no error with `randn` when I remove `cv::`

Tags: c++, opencv

I accidentally forgot the namespace `cv::` when I used `randn` and it has been compiled with no errors. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::cout << "\n%%( Random Generator )%%\n"; 
    cv::Mat G = cv::Mat::ones(4,4, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(1,1, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat s = cv::Mat::ones(1,1, CV_64FC1);
    std::cout << G << std::endl;
    randn(G, m, s);
   std::cout << G << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running the code in Windows

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\xxxx\opencv_2.4.10\build\include /link /LIBPATH:D:\xxxx\opencv_2.4.10\build\x86\vc12\lib opencv_core2410.lib
```

My question is Is this function also defined out of `cv` namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get argument dependent lookup (ADL, also known as Koenig lookup). Essentially the name is looked up in the namespace of the type of the `G` argument, namely `cv::`. ADL mainly helps with finding operators, but also works with ordinary named functions.

Comment: Something new to me. Thanks.